# Atmosphere is unable to configure JSR-356

Tags: java, websocket, jetty, guice, atmosphere

I created Java web application and trying to force atmosphere to use JSR-356 since, as I understood, it's the only way to use original `javax.servlet.HttpSession` from `AtmosphereResource` object.

When I deploy my application to Jetty (v. 9.3.7), I get the following errors:

```
16:45:16.535 [Scanner-1] ERROR org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils - 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage. No Servlet associated with Key[type=org.atmosphere.guice.AtmosphereGuiceServlet, annotation=[none]]
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.guestRawServletPath(IOUtils.java:274) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.guestServletPath(IOUtils.java:248) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.<init>(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:63) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.<init>(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:40) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:234) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:306) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:292) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:2082) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:914) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:838) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.configureFramework(AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.java:75) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:84) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:80) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:75) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:121) [guice-servlet-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:82) [guice-servlet-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:103) [guice-servlet-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:220) [guice-servlet-4.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:137) [jetty-servlet-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:856) [jetty-servlet-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:350) [jetty-servlet-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1379) [jetty-webapp-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1341) [jetty-webapp-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772) [jetty-server-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:263) [jetty-servlet-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:517) [jetty-webapp-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:458) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610) [jetty-util-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529) [jetty-util-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392) [jetty-util-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329) [jetty-util-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) [na:1.8.0_74]
16:45:16.536 [Scanner-1] ERROR o.a.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver - Real error: Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.guestRawServletPath(IOUtils.java:292) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.guestServletPath(IOUtils.java:248) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.<init>(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:63) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356AsyncSupport.<init>(JSR356AsyncSupport.java:40) ~[atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_74]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:234) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:306) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultAsyncSupportResolver.java:292) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereFramework.java:2082) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:914) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.init(AtmosphereFramework.java:838) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.configureFramework(AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.java:75) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:84) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.configureFramework(AtmosphereServlet.java:80) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:75) [atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.init(ServletDefinition.java:121) [guice-servlet-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.init(ManagedServletPipeline.java:82) [guice-servlet-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.initPipeline(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:103) [guice-servlet-4.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.init(GuiceFilter.java:220) [guice-servlet-4.0.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:137) [jetty-servlet-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:856) [jetty-servlet-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:350) [jetty-servlet-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1379) [jetty-webapp-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1341) [jetty-webapp-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772) [jetty-server-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:263) [jetty-servlet-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:517) [jetty-webapp-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:458) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64) [jetty-deploy-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610) [jetty-util-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529) [jetty-util-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392) [jetty-util-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329) [jetty-util-9.3.7.v20160115.jar:9.3.7.v20160115]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) [na:1.8.0_74]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) [na:1.8.0_74]
```

If I force native API to take the precedence with the following code

```
params.put(ApplicationConfig.WEBSOCKET_SUPPRESS_JSR356, "true");
```

then everything works fine.

Here is my deployment descriptor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sample.guice.GuiceContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The module used to provide all the bindings:

```
public class ServerModule extends AbstractModule
{
    @Override
    protected void configure()
    {
        install(new ServletModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configureServlets()
            {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                // params.put(ApplicationConfig.WEBSOCKET_SUPPRESS_JSR356, "true");
                serve("/atmosphere").with(AtmosphereGuiceServlet.class, params);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I omitted the class annotated with `@ManagedService` and some other code since there are no problems. As I said, everything works fine with native websocket API.

Comment: I would recommend using jetty native websocket API over the JSR356 websocket.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt seems that its native API doesn't provide access to `javax.servlet.session.HttpSession` available before handshake, so I have to use JSR-356...

Comment: Access to the `HttpSession` is even easier on the native API vs JSR356.  You have 2 ways. (1) provide your own `WebSocketCreator` and do whatever you want with the upgrade process, including taking the HttpSession and shoving into your websocket class directly. (2) Use the `api.Session#getSession()` to access the `HttpSession` at any time (before the `HttpSession` expires)

Comment: I meant Atmosphere can't handle this case out of the box. Anyway thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

the message:
*Unable to configure jsr356 at that stage*

means, that the jsr356 support needs to be added during ServletContextInitialization phase, the best in a ServletContextListener

my problem is that jetty 9.4 native websocket is not compatible with atmosphere anymore, on the other hand jsr356 is not compatible with guice

I managed to make jsr356 work with vaadin 8.8.1 and jetty 9.4, but it requires the VaadinServlet to be directly managed by Jetty. This doesn't work with Guice, which installs it's own GuiceFilter, and the servlets are not registered to Jetty directly.

look at JSR356WebsocketInitializer.initAtmosphereForVaadinServlet for more information

Comment: This is interesting. We recently fixed similar type of issue in our Spring integration, see: https://github.com/vaadin/spring/pull/437 We added some API in framework see: https://github.com/vaadin/framework/pull/11551/files I assume that this could be helpful also in patching Guice to work, although I am not expert on Guice.

Comment: Meanwhile, I managed to make guice, vaadin 8.8.1 and jetty 9.4 work together. But it's more like a workaround: I let Jetty to create the VaadinServlet implementation instance, then use injector.injectMembers(servlet) to add things that should come from the guice context. This means the servlet itself is not in the guice context, but it wasn't needed in our application.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `ApplicationConfig.JSR356_MAPPING_PATH` initParameter and give it a try.

If it doesn't work ,may be you can initialize atmosphere framework explicitly and specify init param
`ApplicationConfig.JSR356_MAPPING_PATH` as valid key value pair .

For initialization you can see org.atmosphere.cpr.ContainerInitializer and for adding the path while initalizing the atmosphere framework

```
final AtmosphereFramework framework = AtmosphereFrameworkInitializer.newAtmosphereFramework(c, false, true);
// Hack to make jsr356 works. Pretty ugly.
DefaultAsyncSupportResolver resolver = new DefaultAsyncSupportResolver(framework.getAtmosphereConfig());

framework.getAtmosphereConfig().addInitParam(ApplicationConfig.JSR356_MAPPING_PATH,appropriateservletPath);
```